Solve $\dfrac{1}{x}<4$

Solve $\dfrac{1}{x}<4$

$\Rightarrow 4x>1$
$\Rightarrow x>\dfrac{1}{4}$
Pretty straightforward. But it turns out $x<0$ works as well. This is not possible for me to deduce from calculations alone. I fear conceptually I'm missing something when doing inequalities. I need help in understanding.
I even tried assuming $x$ is negative. Hence: $\dfrac{1}{x}<4 \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{x}>4$ But this just changes the question and becomes senseless, besides $x$ that work in $\dfrac{1}{x}>4$ does not work in the original equation.

How do you go from $\frac1x<4$ to $4x>1$?

$x\cdot \frac{1}{x} < 4 \cdot x$

Remember that multiplying by a negative number reverses the inequality, so this only works when $x>0$

But if I assume $x<0$, you'd just get $x\cdot \frac{1}{x} < 4 \cdot x \Rightarrow 1 > 4x \Rightarrow x< \frac{1}{4}$ which is completely wrong when plugging into the original equation.

I am voting to close as (essentially) a duplicate or  repost of your post of yesterday, which received sufficient comments and answer.

If you want equivalent statements, you need to distinguish two cases:
$$\frac{1}{x}<4\iff \left\{\frac{1}{x}<4\text{ and }x<0\right\}\text{ or }\left\{\frac{1}{x}<4\text{ and }x>0\right\}$$
and solve each case. If $x>0$,
$$\frac{1}{x}<4\iff \frac{1}{4}<x$$
and if $x<0$,
$$\frac{1}{x}<4\iff 1>4x\iff \frac{1}{4}>x$$
which is true for all $x<0$. Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{x}<4\iff x\in (-\infty,0)\cup \left(\frac{1}{4},+\infty\right)=\mathbb R\setminus \left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]$$

$\dfrac{1}{x}<4$
$\dfrac{1}{x}-4<0$
$\dfrac{1-4x}{x}<0$
then $0$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ are the critical points.
$x<0$ or $x>\frac{1}{4}$

Consider the equation  $\frac{1}{x} < 4$, then if $x >0$ we have
$\frac{1}{x}\cdot x < 4\cdot x \implies 4x > 1 \implies x > \frac{1}{4}$
Now the other case is $x<0$, then we have
$\frac{1}{x} \cdot x > 4 \cdot x \implies 4x < 1$ which is true for all negative $x$.
The case $x = 0$ does not make sense as $\frac{1}{0}$ is not a number. Hence $x \in (-\infty, 0) \cup (0.25, \infty)$
